# Robotframework: Suite contains no tests in suite

Tags: robotframework

I'm struggling with the `-s --suite` option.
When I run my good all Test case files, like this: `robot .`, everything is fine (i.e. telling robot to run all test cases files in current folder, `.` for current folder). Or, if I want to run particular Test Case file, lets say `robot mytest.robot`, works fine too.

However, recently I have created an init file. That one is being executed when running `robot .` (because it is stored in that directory), but naturally not when running `robot mytest.robot`. So far everything is clear.

I thought the easy solution is to run `robot -s mytest.robot .`
However, I'm getting an error : `Suite 'BDD' contains no tests in suite 'mytest.robot'.`
Which is not right, because as I mentioned above, running it like `robot mytest.robot` from the very same directory works fine, the Test cases in that file are processed.
Moreover, I'm getting the same, even if I run `robot -s non_existent_test_case_file.robot .` >>> `Suite 'BDD' contains no tests in suite 'non_existent_test_case_file.robot'.`, which should sort of also prove that the issue is not with my mytest.robot not having tests specified = the error message is simply wrong.

Using: `Robot Framework 3.1 (Python 3.6.6 on linux)`

Any hints ?

**adding more info**

I have created new folder "temp", where I moved my `__init__.robot` and `mytest.robot` files. I **edited them** so that they are as basic as possible.

`__init__.robot`:

```
*** Settings ***

Suite Setup     RobotSetup
Suite Teardown  RobotTeardown

*** Keywords ***

RobotSetup
    Log To Console    robot init setup

RobotTeardown
    Log To Console    robot init teardown
```

`mytest.robot`:

```
*** Test Cases ***

MyBestTestCase
    Log To Console     hello world
```

RESULTS:

```
[/vagrant/test/bdd/temp]$ ll
total 8
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 vagrant vagrant 213 Jan 23 10:44 __init__.robot
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 vagrant vagrant  74 Jan 23 10:44 mytest.robot

[/vagrant/test/bdd/temp]$ robot .
==============================================================================
Temp
==============================================================================
robot init setup
Temp.Mytest
==============================================================================
MyBestTestCase                                                        hello world
MyBestTestCase                                                        | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Temp.Mytest                                                           | PASS |
1 critical test, 1 passed, 0 failed
1 test total, 1 passed, 0 failed
==============================================================================
robot init teardown
Temp                                                                  | PASS |
1 critical test, 1 passed, 0 failed
1 test total, 1 passed, 0 failed
```

... AND

```
[/vagrant/test/bdd/temp]$ robot -s mytest.robot .
[ ERROR ] Suite 'Temp' contains no tests in suite 'mytest.robot'.
```

Comment: have you checked this https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/issues/2498?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you're telling robot to run the suite "robot" in the suite "mytest", and it can't find a suite named "robot". Since it can't find a suite named "robot", then it certainly can't find any tests in the suite named "robot".

When you use `--suite`, you do not give it filenames, you must give it test suite names. In your case you would run robot with `robot -s mytest .`.

Comment: omg, my stupid mistake. You are absolutely right. It works that way, thanks !